# Why doesn't Docker's registry need host network mode set when running it's container to access it using the host's FQDN?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-network

When setting up a registry that includes authorization and SSL (and perhaps without - I haven't tested it), such as in [this example](https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/airgap-disconnected-installation-of-openshift-4-2-abd7794fc7fe), the user is able to `curl` into the registry container using the host's fully qualified domain name and the port that has been exposed:

```
curl -u admin:password https://mirror-ocp-registry.ibmcloud.io.cpak:5000/v2/_catalog
```

It is my understanding, based on [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) that in order for a connection to be established with the container using the host's domain and port information one would need to set `--network host` when running the container. Is this somehow established within the build process or am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `host` network mode?

Comment: host network is so you can access `localhost:...` as the host.  if you're using the fqdn and it's resolving to a non-local ip address (even if it would have been accessible through just localhost) then it's fine to use the normal networking stack

Comment: Host networking is almost never necessary (and doesn't work on MacOS).  The standard way to reach a container is through the host's FQDN and a published port (`docker run -p`, Compose `ports:`).  So if you started the container with `docker run -p 5000:5000 ...` (and _without_ `--net host`) you could reach that URL.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Interesting. I was working on creating an RPM repository recently, and trying to curl into it using the fqdn and port and it wasn't successful. I assumed this was the reason, but I must have overlooked the actual cause.

Comment: If either of you would like to put your responses in an answer I'll accept it.